# How to get json, store for offline situations and synchronize when online?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, service-worker

I am in the process of developing a PWA based on a website. I have an internal html page which json provides. I can read this page via Ajax and parse. Since the Ajax call does not work in offline mode, I'm looking for the right way to make json data available offline. I have read a lot, also about the different methods. My request, is there a tutorial or can someone give me a hint.
I'm looking for an easy way, preferably with Jquery to make a Json file available for the offline case. And it should syncronize when the user is back online.
Thank you very much.

```
myJson.html

{  
   "map":[  

   ],
   "data":[  
      {  
         "title":"Eintrag 1",
         "alias":"eintrag-1",
         "id":"1",
         "tstamp":"08\/16\/2019 14:23",
         "sorting":"128",
         "pid":"0",
         "stop":"",
         "start":"",
         "invisible":"",
         "useSocialSharingButtons":false,
         "masterUrl":"",
         "hasGoBackLink":false,
         "contentElements":"",
         "_moduleId":"79",
         "timeFormat":"H:i",
         "dateFormat":"m\/d\/Y",
         "hasOperations":false,
         "dateTimeFormat":"m\/d\/Y H:i",
         "readMore":"Weiterlesen \u2026",
         "entityIndex":[  
            1,
            2
         ],
         "cssClass":" odd first"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Eintrag 2",
         "alias":"eintrag-2",
         "id":"2",
         "tstamp":"08\/16\/2019 14:23",
         "sorting":"64",
         "pid":"0",
         "stop":"",
         "start":"",
         "invisible":"",
         "useSocialSharingButtons":false,
         "masterUrl":"",
         "hasGoBackLink":false,
         "contentElements":"",
         "_moduleId":"79",
         "timeFormat":"H:i",
         "dateFormat":"m\/d\/Y",
         "hasOperations":false,
         "dateTimeFormat":"m\/d\/Y H:i",
         "readMore":"Weiterlesen \u2026",
         "entityIndex":[  
            2,
            2
         ],
         "cssClass":" even last"
      }
   ],
   "output":"",
   "message":"",
   "pagination":null,
   "showAsGroup":false,
   "operations":[  

   ]
}

my output html

<script>
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){  

    var displayResources = $("#display-resources");

    displayResources.text("Loading data from JSON source...");

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "myJson.html",


      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.data[0].title);
        var output =
          "<table><thead><tr><th>Title</th><th>Alias</th><th>ID</th></thead><tbody>";
        for (var i in result.data) {
          output +=
            "<tr><td>" +
            result.data[i].title +
            "</td><td>" +
            result.data[i].alias +
            "</td><td>" +
            result.data[i].id +
            "</td></tr>";
        }
        output += "</tbody></table>";

        displayResources.html(output);
        $("table").addClass("table");
      }
    });

});
</script>

<div id="display-resources"></div>
```

Comment: Google "localStorage".

Comment: It would help it you included the actual code (all of the relevant parts) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my first post here. I added the relevant data. This feature works great online. But not offline.

Comment: The myJson.html is created locally from the mysql db. I would like to cache them, parse them and if the user is online update them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `localStorage` to store data in the client-side (browser) temporarily. It's a simple key-value store and can be accessed in the following way:

```
// Store 
localStorage.key = value
// Fetch
var value = localStorage.key
```

Whether or not the user is connected determine that based on HTTP response or some other mechanism. When offline use `localStorage` and when back to online fetch from the server and update `localStorage`.